# Dataframe, multiple cell value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need a help with pandas dataframe.
I have dataframe with following columns:

```
Surname, project, project_type, city, value
```

Cells in columns "project" and "city" have more than one value, separated by '/'. Max number of values in such cells might be variable. 
For every of such a row (with multiples values inside cell) I need to decompose it into separated rows with only one value in columns project and city.
Rest values in other columns keep the same.

```
"Surname"; "project";   "Project_type"; "City";  "value"
```

- Smith;  PR_A/PR_B; L; Lon/NY/LA; 10,000
- Johnson; PR_A; S;  Paris/Toronto; 8,000
- Sunshine; PR_C/PR_A/PR_B; L; Lon/NY/LA/Toronto;   17,000
- Archibald; PR_D; S; LA; 6,000
  .....

Anybody has any idea ?
If number of values is constant, would not make me trouble, but this is a challenge, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe need [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but first split values by `/`:

```
from  itertools import product
a=pd.DataFrame([j for i in df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('/')).values for j in product(*i)],
                  columns=df.columns)
print (a)
      Surname project Project_type     City   value
0       Smith    PR_A            L      Lon  10,000
1       Smith    PR_A            L       NY  10,000
2       Smith    PR_A            L       LA  10,000
3       Smith    PR_B            L      Lon  10,000
4       Smith    PR_B            L       NY  10,000
5       Smith    PR_B            L       LA  10,000
6     Johnson    PR_A            S    Paris   8,000
7     Johnson    PR_A            S  Toronto   8,000
8    Sunshine    PR_C            L      Lon  17,000
9    Sunshine    PR_C            L       NY  17,000
10   Sunshine    PR_C            L       LA  17,000
11   Sunshine    PR_C            L  Toronto  17,000
12   Sunshine    PR_A            L      Lon  17,000
13   Sunshine    PR_A            L       NY  17,000
14   Sunshine    PR_A            L       LA  17,000
15   Sunshine    PR_A            L  Toronto  17,000
16   Sunshine    PR_B            L      Lon  17,000
17   Sunshine    PR_B            L       NY  17,000
18   Sunshine    PR_B            L       LA  17,000
19   Sunshine    PR_B            L  Toronto  17,000
20  Archibald    PR_D            S       LA   6,000
```